# Imbed a login form into multiple webpages

Tags: forms, html

Basically I want have a login area at the top of all my web pages. Currently I have written the form code on each webpage individually however i feel this is not the right way to do it. Is it possible to just have one file that handles the form (eg signinform.php) and imbed it in each page?

Thanks!

snippet code for include:

```
<nav id="nav1"></nav>
<div id="main">

    <h1>JMX206 OUTER PLANETARY MINING</h1>

    <p><a href="SignUp.html">Create your account</a></p>

    <?php include ("loginform.php");?>
```

loginform.php:

```
<table>
<form action="./signin_engine.php"  method="post">
<tr><td>Username:</td>
    <td><input  name="username" type="text" id="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input  name="password" type="password" id="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr> <td></td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in">
     <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

signin_engine.php:

```
<?php

include("session.php");

include("db_conn.php");

//receive username and data from the form
$user=$_POST['username'];
//check if username is in the table
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//convert result to array
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//if the username from database is not the same from the form

if($row['username']!=$user || $user=="")
{
header('Location:./loginform.php?error=invalid_username');
}

else
{
if($row['password']==$password)
{
    //save username in the session
    $session_user=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['session_user']=$session_user;
    header('Location:./signin_success.php');
}

else
{
    header('Location:./loginform.php?error=invalid_password);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: oh my god how did i not know of this lol. thanks so much

Comment: welcome, dont forget to accept my answer below

Answer (score 1):

implement this `include` to all your webpage

```
 <?php include("signinform.php");?>
```

Comment: hmm the line of code isnt doing anything. the form isnt printed onto the pages where i link that line of code.

Comment: Can you give snippet code where you put the line of code?

Comment: code has been uploaded, do you require the form also?

Comment: yes as I need to know where the `action` form goes to.

Comment: looks like the path of your main page located in the root. Is that your `loginform.php` located inside other folder?

Comment: all files are in the same folder. so yea im confused as to why its not working!

Comment: The main page is called index.html will this classification break the code?

Comment: inside `<form action="./signin_engine.php"  method="post">` remove the `./` as it access to parent directory